Is there a way to prevent modification of an S4 object in R?
I want to create an S4 class that is a subclass of another S4 class, with additional constraints (like the object should be sorted). Given that modifications of the object could result in violations of the constraints, I would like to make the object immutable. Is there a way to do this? Perhaps call validObject() after a method is called.

This is with S3 but I think the same principle applies to creating a method for <- and any other ways you have to write to the object. However, I think this might be overkill, not very idiomatic for R, and not a guarantee anyway (R has no equivalent of a sealed or final method so determined users could overwrite whatever you implement). I would just make a defined way to create an object of this class which is guaranteed to be valid, and document that users should not do anything else.

I suppose that is the R way.

I'm trying to imagine the fun that writing the is.sorted(x, y) test would entail, without even going to modifications upon the super or sub object and their implications. 'it is not meant to be called directly', is how this is sometimes termed, but 'users should not do anything else' puts this more explicitly, i.e. don't break the working thing. And your use case?

I want to enforce certain class properties so that I can write methods that assume those properties. This is both for correctness and speed. Certain properties might be expensive to check as well so preventing modification would be more efficient than adding a validity check at the start of every method.

@Chris "Note that validity methods do not have to check validity of superclasses: validObject calls such methods explicitly." from ?validObject. In my answer, I write the validity methods for each C2 and C1 separately. when I call validObject on a C2 object, it will automatically check that that object is also a valid C1 object by calling the C1 validity method. I think writing the validity methods in S4 is quite simple and easy to reason about.

My approach is to create a secured environment (called SEnv below) where all objects are checked by validObject before entering into this secured environment. Then, anytime you take out any objects from this secured environment, you can be sure they are valid objects without rechecking them.
setClass("SEnv", contains = "environment")

setMethod(
    "[[<-",
    signature(x = "SEnv", i = "character", j = "missing", value = "ANY"),
    function(x, i, j, ..., value) {
        validObject(value, complete = TRUE)
        ev <- as(x, "environment")
        ev[[i]] <- value
        lockBinding(i, ev)
        x
    }
)

setMethod(
    "$<-",
    signature(x = "SEnv", value = "ANY"),
    function(x, name, value) {
        validObject(value, complete = TRUE)
        ev <- as(x, "environment")
        ev[[name]] <- value
        lockBinding(name, ev)
        x
    }
)

Example

Let's define a C1 class with 2 slots: x as integer and y as character. We also add a constraint that x and y must have the same length.

setClass("C1", slots = c(x = "integer", y = "character"))
setValidity("C1", function(object) {
    res <- rep(NA_character_, 1)
    if (length(object@x) != length(object@y)) res[[1]] <- "length of slot x and y must equal"
    res <- c(na.omit(res))
    res <- if (length(res)) res else TRUE
    res
})


The C2 class extends the C1 class and adds an additional constraint which requires slot x to be sorted.

setClass("C2", contains = c("C1"))
setValidity("C2", function(object) {
    res <- rep(NA_character_, 1)
    if (is.unsorted(object@x) && is.unsorted(rev(object@x))) res[[1]] <- "slot x is not sorted"
    res <- c(na.omit(res))
    res <- if (length(res)) res else TRUE
    res
})


Test drive

ee <- new("SEnv")
ee[["o1"]] <- new("C2", x = c(10L:1L), y = rep("A", 10))
ee$o2 <- 1:5 # this is a valid integer object
ee$o2 <- 6:10 # object `o2` is locked and cannot change

# Try to create a malformed `C2` object 
o_bad <- ee$o1
o_bad@x <- c(5L, 6L, 7L)
o_bad # Even though the object is a malformed `C2`, it is still printed as "An object of class "C2"" and method dispatch through signature `C2`.
#An object of class "C2"
#Slot "x":
#[1] 5 6 7
#Slot "y":
# [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"

ee$o3 <- o_bad # this bad object cannot enter our secured environment due to failure of validity method of its superclass `C1`
# Error in validObject(value, complete = TRUE) : 
#  invalid class “C2” object: length of slot x and y must equal


This is nice. But I think the point still stands that a user could do setMethod("$<-",signature(x = "SEnv", value = "ANY"), \(x, name, value) { ev <- as(x, "environment"); ev[[name]] <- value; x}) and then merrily assign whatever the like to the secure environment. So it does provide some protection - but I don't think in R there are any guarantees if someone is really determined.
